# Digest updates parent controller before child directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller and a directive. The directive has isolate scope with a `=` two-way var named `counter` and an `&` expression named `tick()`.

The directive will update `counter` and call `tick()` right after.

The problem is the order in which these operations happen:

1. `counter` updated in directive
2. `tick()` called on controller
3. `counter` updated in controller

I've managed to work around his by using `setTimeout(tick,0);`, but it's kind of a hack.
Another solution would be for `tick()` to accept a param (the value of `counter`).

Is there a better solution than the ones I described above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Zen of Angular](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY#t=1773) suggests:

```
Treat scope as read only in templates
Treat scope as write only in controllers
```

Avoid reading the value `counter` in the controller. Instead, pass it as an argument from the template.

The `setTimeout` trick is a hack and one should avoid relying on the order of execution of various watchers in `$digest` loops.

Comment: I see. So you're saying the second option is the best way of dealing with this?

Comment: Also, when you say `templates` you're referring to html files or directives?

Comment: @Francisc `templates` always refers to the HTML and yes, the second way (passing the parameter as an argument to the `tick` function) is a better way to deal with this, though it means that the value will have to pass through your `directive` in this case.

Comment: I was asking because in my case it's directive and controller, no templates, so wasn't sure if you were calling directives templates.